# PowerShell Add-Type OracleManagedDataAccess.dll without full path

Tags: .net, oracle, powershell, odp.net

I am using PowerShell against Oracle with much success.

I am using the ODP Managed Provider. Since the provider can be installed in different locations, the `Add-Type -Path` needs to point differently on different machines.

I would like to be able to refer to this assembly in a way that does not rely on full path to the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution, which relies on knowing the strong name of the wanted assembly. It seems to work reliably on the testing that I have done

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342")
```

Comment: I see that this works. But, how is this any better than a hardcoded directory path when Oracle has a new version or the code is run on a machine with a different version?

Comment: This does not rely on the path where the provider is installed. If the code is run on a machine with a newer provider, this code will (most probably) be redirected, because the newer provider installs a publisher policy that will send requests for assembly ver x-1 to ver x.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could potentially get the install directory from the Registry with PowerShell. One possible location is here:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed
```

Although that might vary depending on which .NET version is installed. You could try a wildcard for that:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\*\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed
```

And ultimately you might need to get value of one of the properties of that registry key, for example if it's the '(default)' value:

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\*\AssemblyFoldersEx\odp.net.managed).'(default)'
```

Comment: Seems AssemblyFoldersEx is not present in the 64-bit framework.